# chrome messaging from background to content script to background again

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I am trying to send data from the local storage of the chrome background page to a content script then do some manipulation with the data. After that I want to send it back to the background page and update the local storage for the background page. Is this possible. I know how to send the data from background to content script, but how do you send from content script to background?

**background.html**

```
var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse, getBackResponse) {
    if (request.extensionSettings === "storage") {

        // send local storage data {"one": "data", "two": "data"}
        sendResponse({storageString: background.localStorage.extdata});

        // save new data from content script
        localStorage.setItem("extdata", getBackResponse);
    }
 });
```

**script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({extensionSettings: "storage"}, function(response) {
  var json = JSON.parse(response.storageString);

  console.log(json);
  // take json object do a few things with data
  // take data and make new json string, and send it background page
  sendBack('{"one": "new data", "two": "more new data"}');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright in this case you just want to differentiate between the messages you send to the background page. One way to do that would be with a simple identifier like this:

**Content Script**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method:"getStorage",extensionSettings:"storage"},
function(response) {
  var json = JSON.parse(response.storageString);

  console.log(json);
  // take json object do a few things with data
  // take data and make new json string, and send it background page
  // Let's just say that `sendBack` is now defined to be a var
  // With the info you want to send back
  var sendBack = {"one": "new data", "two": "more new data"};
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method:"setStorage", newData:sendBack});
});
```

With this, we send a message to get the data, manipulate it in the callback and then send it back. Now to handle it.

**Background Page**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(message.method == "getStorage"){
    if(message.extensionSettings === "storage") {
      // send local storage data {"one": "data", "two": "data"}
      sendResponse({storageString: background.localStorage.extdata});
    }
  }
  else if(message.method == "setStorage"){
    // save new data from content script
    localStorage.setItem("extdata", message.newData);
  }
});
```

This way we can handle a variety of different types of messages just by changing the value of `method` or whatever you want to name it.